# Apexchart: Multiple track Colors in Radialbar Chart Multiple

Tags: javascript, apex, apexcharts

We are trying to make a design like each bar has unique track color instead of common colors in multiple bars, But i didnt find related help in documentation. Kindly someone help me to solve this.

Following is my working code,

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'radialBar',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            radialBar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    track: {
                        background: '#000000',
                        startAngle: -135,
                        endAngle: 135,
                    },
                    name: {
                        fontSize: '22px',
                    },
                    value: {
                        fontSize: '16px',
                    },
                    total: {
                        show: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [44, 55, 67, 83],
        labels: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Berries'],

    }

   var chart = new ApexCharts(
        document.querySelector("#chart"),
        options
    );

    chart.render();
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Multiple track colors in radialBar are not implemented currently but will be available in v2.4.0

You will be able to do it like this

```
plotOptions: {
   radialBar: {
     track: {
       background: ['#f3f3f3', '#e4e4e4']
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yet to wait for next version.